# How to make background image of a button responsive

Tags: css, jsp

code I use in jsp is

```
<button class="refresh" onclick="javascript:regenImage();" type="button"></button>
```

CSS I use to put image on that button is

```
.refresh{
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("../images/sp_out.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 40px;
    width: 43px;
}
```

by using image is not getting responsive.

Comment: what do you mean by responsive. Beacuse here you width and height are fixed for the button.

Comment: For your onclick, it should be `onclick="regenImage();"`

Comment: size of image getting set  according to the screen size.....

Comment: onclick works fine problem is only in the backgroud image of the button...

Comment: can you post a fiddle.  may be try `background-size:cover`

Answer (score 0):

You need add

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

it means that the width of background will be 100% and height auto;

or you can add like this

```
 background-size: auto 100%;
```

or

```
 background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: Thank you Aram Mkrtchyan but still have the same issue

Comment: can you put some example, it will be easy to help you. welcome